# Distributions of random numbers of functions rand and randn

Tags: matlab

I want to know what distribution the **rand** function and the **randn** function have.
In the documentation, I read that the **rand** function has an equiprobable distribution, and the **randn** normal function.
Everywhere they write differently

My task is to generate pseudo-random numbers in the range from -0.1 to 0.1, equally distributed. I don't know what matlab function I can use.

It is important to have an equiprobable distribution, not a normal one (aka Gaussian).

Comment: _Everywhere they write differently_ What do you mean?

Comment: “equiprobable” means equally likely. “equiprobable distribution” thus is the same as “uniform distribution”. Though I doubt that the MATLAB documentation for `rand` doesn’t say “uniform distribution”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> - [`rand()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)  returns a single uniformly distributed random number in the interval (0,1).
> - [`randn()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html?searchHighlight=randn&s_tid=srchtitle) returns a random scalar drawn from the standard normal distribution.

So to generate a random number uniformely distributed on `(-0.1, 0.1)` you can use

```
y = rand() * 0.2 - 0.1
```